# Full text search score projection in new MongoDB driver for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search, projection

I'm upgrading my code from old PHP MongoDB driver:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php

To new MongoDB driver:
http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

In previous version I had this:

```
$db->collection->find([ 
  '$text' => [ '$search' => "stackoverflow" ]
],
[ 
  'score' => [ '$meta' => 'textScore' ]
])->sort([ 'sort' => [ 'score' => [ '$meta' => 'textScore' ] ] ]);
```

In a new version, there is no sort function on cursor any more, you have to pass it as an option. So new code is like this:

```
$db->collection->find([ 
    '$text' => [ '$search' => 'stackoverflow' ]
],
[ 
  'score' => [ '$meta' => 'textScore' ],
  'sort' => [ 'score' => [ '$meta' => 'textScore' ] ]
]);
```

But I'm getting an error:
"BadValue must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys"

It's because, score projection is not happening anymore. If you just remove sort option and log result, you will see, that there is no score in the results array. There is no documentation about it at all.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you want to search a Mongo text index and sort on the textScore field with the new PHP driver, you have to use the Query class, add your filter and options there and then execute using the Manager class. In your case it would be something like this:

```
$filter = [
    '$text' => ['$search' => 'stackoverflow']];

$options =  [
    'projection' => [
        'score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']
            ],
    'sort' => [
        'score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']
        ]
];

$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://yourdbserver:27017");
$mongoQuery = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $mng->executeQuery('db_name.collection_name', $mongoQuery);
```

See the documentation page for the [Query class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-query.php), the first note appears to be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way too:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->DB->COLLECTION;
$cursor = $collection->find(
                ['$text' => ['$search' => 'stackoverflow']],
                [
                'projection' => [
                    'score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']
                    ],
                'sort' => [
                    'score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']
                    ]
                ]
            );
```

And with skip and limit:

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->DB->COLLECTION;
$cursor = $collection->find(
                ['$text' => ['$search' => 'stackoverflow']],
                ['skip' => 0, 
                'limit' => 20,
                'projection' => [
                    'score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']
                    ],
                'sort' => [
                    'score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']
                    ]
                ]
            );
```